# About passing instances of objects to other classes

Tags: java, class, instance

Let's say I have two classes. `Class1` and `Class2`.

The constructor of `Class2` looks like this:

```
public Class2{

Class1 c;

    public Class2(Class1 c){
        this.c = c;
    }

}
```

When creating an instance of Class2 inside the code of Class1, we pass the existing instance of Class1 to Class2. This is from Class1:

```
Class2 c2 = new Class2(this);
```

Inside Class2, I want to manipulate the variables inside the instance of Class1 that's been passed to Class2.

My question is:

If I make changes to the `c` (the instance of Class1 that's been passed to Class2), am I affecting the *original* instance of Class1, or just a copy?

Comment: `c` is a **reference**...

Comment: You are affecting the original since objects are passed by reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference